# Serving django Admin files with Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, django-admin, mod-wsgi

I'm having trouble getting Apache to serve the admin media for django (using ver. 1.1). My ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX is set to the default:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
```

And I've modified my Apache setup:

```
Alias /media/ /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/admin/media/

<Directory /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/admin/media/>
     AllowOverride None
     Options None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here and why it isn't working. I've seen a lot of questions like this asked, but can not determine why I'm still having the problem.

EDIT: Apache logs

```
[Sun Mar 11 20:14:18 2012] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sun Mar 11 20:14:18 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1220142448,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Sun Mar 11 20:14:18 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1220142448,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Sun Mar 11 20:14:18 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1220142448,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Sun Mar 11 20:14:18 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1220142448,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Sun Mar 11 20:14:18 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1220142448,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Sun Mar 11 20:14:18 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14 with Suhosin-Patch mod_wsgi/2.8 Python/2.6.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 11 20:14:23 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1220142448,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Sun Mar 11 20:14:23 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1220142448,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Sun Mar 11 20:14:35 2012] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1220142448,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Comment: Did u restarded Apache and all other components?

Comment: When you say "apache is still trying to pull the CSS from /media/", how are you determining that? Even when correctly configured, the HTML itself is still going to say `/media/`.

Comment: I did restart everything. Amber, I do not know then that Apache is trying to access /media/ then. I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: I've updated my post with the Apache log

Comment: What is the error you get when you browse a file in `/media/` from Apache? I suspect this is a permissions problem since your file system location is a place where normally Apache doesn't have any access.

Comment: FWIW, the KeyError warnings merely indicate you are using an old and obsolete mod_wsgi version and should upgrade. They are nothing to do with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.3 added new cotrib app django.contrib.staticfiles:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/

"Django will now expect to find the admin static files under the URL /admin/", so now ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX is deprecated - alias in Apache setup is sufficient, ex:

```
Alias /static/admin/ /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/contrib/admin/media/
```

This works for me.